# Custom UI Runtime Error in Outlook plugin

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in, ribbon

I added a new ribbon to my plugin project (vsto). Added a button which is supposed to appear in all "meeting" forms. (**New Items > Meeting**). So I did the following in order to do that:

[image]

In other words, I tried to add the appropriate Office Control ID to associate it with any New Meeting form.

Now, whenever I open and outlook email item for the first time (i.e. post startup of outlook), I get the following error message.

[image]

How to make this go away...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very hard to understand why this happens. Especially if there is a designer involved.

On the ribbon designer, if I view the properties of the ribbon, I noticed I've set multiple ribbon types.

[image]

After I've unchecked for the read item, everything is back to normal.